# Mercurial convert filename encoding

Tags: mercurial, encoding, crucible

I have Mercurial repositories running on Apache with mod_wsgi. Repositories have all filenames encoded in windows-1251. This encoding is used for historically reasons: they were converted to mercurial from svn, windows-1251 is default windows encoding for russian locale.

Now programmers want to use [Crucible](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CRUCIBLE/About+Crucible) tool for code review. It can't undersand filenames in any other encoding than utf-8. So I need to convert them from windows-1251 to utf-8. Does anyone know how to do this? Mercurial convert extension doesn't have options to convert encodings.

hgweb.config:

```
[web]
#encoding = UTF-8
encoding = windows-1251
#allow_archive = gz, zip, bz2
allow_archive = zip
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false

[extensions]

[collections]
/data/mercurial = /data/mercurial
```

Comment: Russian filenames?! Don't think about file-rename?

Comment: I'm system administrator, not developer, my duty is to provide stable working service, not to learn how to use it.

Comment: Matt Mackall [wrote](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.bazaar-ng.general/21737) long time ago, maybe already outdated # If you'd like to serve pages with UTF-8 instead of your default
# locale charset, you can do so by uncommenting the following lines.
# Note that this will cause your .hgrc files to be interpreted in
# UTF-8 and all your repo files to be displayed using UTF-8.
#
#import os
#os.environ["HGENCODING"] = "UTF-8"

Comment: I've written in comments to below answer:

Changing `encoding = windows-1251` to `encoding = UTF-8` just made filenames unreadable. This is because they are stored in windows-1251. "UTF-8"os.environ["HGENCODING"] = "UTF-8" is equal to this setting.

Answer (score 7):

You are right that the convert extension doesn't support this in a nice way currently. That is, you cannot ask it to recode from encoding *X* to encoding *Y*. However, you can ask it to rename the files one by one for you! First create a file called `rename.py` with

```py
import sys
for path in sys.stdin:
    old = path[:-1] # strip newline
    new = old.decode("cp1251").encode("utf-8")
    print 'rename "%s" "%s"' % (old, new)
```

Then run

```
$ hg manifest --all | python rename.py > rename.txt
```

This creates your file map. You can now use

```
$ hg convert --filemap rename.txt cp1251-repo utf-8-repo
```

to convert the repository into a new repository. In the new repository, it will look like the files have always been saved using UTF-8 file names.

**Note:** The file names are now stored as UTF-8 in the repository. This means that checkouts will look fine on moderns Linux machines. Windows, however, does not use UTF-8 file names. The [FixUtf-8 extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixUtf8Extension) must be used to make Mercurial convert the UTF-8 file names into UTF-16 on the fly. This will create readable file names on Windows too.

**Note:** Everybody will have to re-clone the new repository! Changing any part of the history inevitably changes all the changesets hashes too. So to pull this off, you need to either

1. make everybody push to the server,
2. convert the repositories on the server,
3. have people re-clone

or

1. make everybody run the above commands on their local repositories
2. convert the repositories on the server

Either way works since the conversion is deterministic and so your users can run it themselves if they have Python available. If they only have a TortoiseHg installation, then it's probably easiest if you convert for them on your server.

I looked at making the convert extension support this more directly and [have sent a patch to the Mercurial mailinglist](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2011-December/036470.html) for more direct support for this.

Comment: I've posted a [full patch](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2011-December/036470.html) on the mailinglist.

Comment: Crucible evangelist has left our company, so the problem disappeared. Thank you very much for writing code to fix my problem and improvement of mercurial :) I'll try this when I'll have some free time.

Comment: Ah, problem solved :-) Feel free to accept my answer when you've tried it out.

Comment: No hg --manifest all in mercurial 1.8. I've userd hg --manifest -r tip. Everything works on Linux machine: I see proper filenames in repo with encoding = UTF-8 in hgweb.config and filenames are correct in cloned repository. On Windows machine I've got "РџРѕСЏСЃРЅРёС‚РµР»СЊРЅР°СЏ Р·Р°РїРёСЃРєР°.docx" filename after clone.

Comment: Yes, this is to be expected — the file names are not recoded when you clone onto Windows and so your checkout becomes garbage. Use the FixUtf8 extension for now.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\selivanov\Рабочий стол\test-utf-8>hg addremove -s 100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hg", line 42, in <module>
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 27, in run
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 64, in dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 127, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\ui.pyo", line 606, in warn
  File "mercurial\extensions.pyo", line 182, in wrap
  File "s:\tortoisehg\hg-fixutf8\fixutf8.py", line 140, in f
    win32helper.rawprint(h, ''.join(args))
  File "s:\tortoisehg\hg-fixutf8\win32helper.py", line 84, in rawprint

Comment: u = s.decode('utf-8')
  File "encodings\utf_8.pyo", line 16, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 54: invalid
continuation byte

Comment: FixUtf8 does not work for me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2040/discussion-between-martin-geisler-and-selivanov-pavel)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I needed to convert bunch of repositories, so I wrote a script that converts all repositories given as list.

**usage:**

```
hg_convert_filenames_encoding.py [-h] [-i INPUT_ENCODING] [-o OUTPUT_ENCODING] [-b] [-u] [repositories [repositories ...]]
```

You can get from [my repository](https://bitbucket.org/rominf/hg_convert_filenames_encoding/overview) at BitBucket.

Answer (score 0):

Just extraction from [Mercurial Wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EncodingStrategy#Unknown_byte_strings) FYI

> The following are explicitly treated as binary data in an unknown
>   encoding:
>
> - file contents
> - file names
>
> These items should be treated as binary data
>   and preserved losslessly wherever possible.

Thus, I suppose, just changing presentation charset in `encoding =` may do the thick

If this assumption is wrong (it's always possible), try [FixUtf8 Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FixUtf8Extension), read part Fixing existing filenames from readme carefully

Comment: Changing `encoding = windows-1251` to `encoding = UTF-8` just made filenames unreadable.

FixUtf8 didn't help too.

Comment: OK. Try to return back encoding = windows-1251 and try `AddDefaultCharset utf-8` in Apache. Another idea - change WAMP to LAMP with UTF8 as locale and do nothing with filenames but have `encoding = UTF-8` again

Comment: This _is_ LAMP. In old days repository was placed on WAMP with Subversion, later I converted it to Mercurial and moved to Linux machine, with UTF-8 locale. `encoding = windows-1251` was set because data was already in this encoding.

Comment: re-read Wiki! 1251 is only presentation layer, not storage

Comment: _are explicitly treated as binary data in an unknown encoding_
And this encoding is windows-1251, filenames are stored in it. I need some way to convert them to UTF-8